# calculate percentage row by row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentage

I have a dataframe, df, i want to calculate percentage by row for one of the rows and return 'No' in the other row.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 500 | 250 | 50.00 |
| Y | 980 | 700 | 71.42 |

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 500 | 250 | 50.00 | 70.08 |
| Y | 980 | 700 | 71.42 | No |

70.08% is got by dividing 50.00/71.42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# shift by a row and divide the two values

df['E']=df['D'].div(df['D'].shift(-1)).fillna('No')
df
```

```
    A     B       C         D   E
0   X   500     250     50.00   0.700084
1   Y   980     700     71.42   No
```